# automatic push using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am pushing update manually using TortoiseGit. I want to push my work automatically daily basis. Is there any way using Task Scheduler or other ? I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a scheduled task that will run in your repository the command

```
git push origin master
```

No need to use TortoiseGit here since the push isn't supposed to be done by a human.

---

*update*

What the command `git push origin master` does:

- `push` tells git to push
- `origin` tells git on which remote repo to push. When you clone a repo, the original one is by default designated as `origin`. So I assume that's where you want to push
- `master` tells git which branch to push. Here it will push your `master` local branche to the `master` branch of the remote repository

(Obviously you may want to adapt part of that command if you want to push elsewhere / another branch.)

So this is it: we have a command we can run in our repo in order to push our latest commit. No we want to run it automatically on a daily basis. This is where we could use a cron on Linux, or a scheduled task on Windows.

Nothing tricky here: just create a scheduled task (eg http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) and configure it to run this command, daily, in the directory where our repo is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
As i am new in git and basically using Tortoise, so not much experienced with these commands. I would appreciate if you elaborate your answer , just thinking i am just starting a b c d in git. Like step by step instruction will be great.
pardon me if i am asking very basic .. Thanks again.