# How to automatically push in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

Is there any way, when I click this :

[image]

it directly commited/pushed,   without further extra need to click the "Commit&push" button again in next window.

[image]

Comment: You want to push the local changes directly to remote repository?

Comment: Just clarifying... geez. Good luck with your quest.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - you need to enter a commit message (this is essential in Git so that you know afterwards what the reason for the change was).

Comment: I already have pre-defined commit message in `.gitconfig` for that project

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672327/automatic-push-using-tortoisegit) help?